# Cannot get web view to work on Android sdk 1.6

Tags: android, webview

I get a blank screen when I try to fill it with a web view on the android. 
The program runs with out errors, but i get a blank screen. 
I'm ussin g sdk 1.6 and running it in  the simulator

The code
package mikenorman.org;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class cBlog extends Activity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blog);

WebView  mWebView;
mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.bwebpage);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.besttechsolutions.biz");
}
```

the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<WebView

android:id="@+id/bwebpage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
/>
```

}
}
-Ted

Comment: wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Is the command to enable javascript in your webview if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Change your linear layout  to "fill_parent" instead of "wrap-content"

Also you should add `</LinearLayout>` to the bottom of the layout file.  Your Linear Layout is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission to your manifest so that you can actually load the remote resources?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

You should be seeing an error if that's the issue, but sometimes folks miss it in the log.

Comment: Hi, Thank you!!! I cannot get my code to work that reads and writes to files, do I need to add permission for it to?